# How to solve Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE?

Tags: java, selenium, jar, selenium-webdriver, dependencies

I'm trying to upload a file using Selenium web driver. Above error receive. I know code is ok. Most of post saying it is because "dependencies". How can I solve it? I checked there was no same name jar files. Here I have show some screen shot of my jar files. How can I solve this dependencies problem?

Java code:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

    public class FusekiStart {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Selenium config  */
        String PROXY = "localhost:3030";

        org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
        proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY)
             .setFtpProxy(PROXY)
             .setSslProxy(PROXY);
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
        driver.get("http://localhost:3030/control-panel.tpl");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Select']")).click();
                           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\Ontology.owl"); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Upload']")).click(); 

}
```

}

Error message:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>      (DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:52)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:56)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<clinit>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:46)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:72)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:84)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<clinit>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:59)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:147)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:112)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:55)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:99)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:93)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
at uom.brts.statisticalmt.FusekiStart.main(FusekiStart.java:39)
```

[image: Jar files]

[image: Jar files web app]

Comment: Do you trying to upload from local pc to website?

Comment: @HelpingHands Yep. I start some server locally(localhost) and try to upload a file. Code is working. Because I uploaded file another java package that not contain all these jar files. I think some wrong with these jar files. May it happen with some conflict with jar files?

Comment: YES then you should first integrate missing jars.

Comment: Where is the code around 'main(FusekiStart.java:39)' that is the line of code to raise Error?　I'm not sure that you code is absolutely OK without evidence.

Comment: @Fumu7 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap); Code is working. I tried in another package.

Comment: @HelpingHands Not missing actually. All jar files (selenium-server..jar) also here. The error came when I tried add code into this package and after adding new selenium jar file. Can it may some conflict with selenium-server jar file and other jar files?

Comment: @Maduri - Nope, there is not conflict possibility there.

Comment: @HelpingHands Do you know what is mean by dependencies issue? Most of post saying that kind of problem may be reason. What may be the reason this code work in some other package which contain only selenium-server jar file and not work here?

Comment: @Maduri - do you using maven plugin?

Comment: @HelpingHands Not actually.

Comment: can you please share code @line 39?

Comment: @VivekSingh WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap); [line 39]

Comment: @Maduri   -   have you imported ? package org.apache.http.impl.io;& package com.jai.http;

Comment: @HelpingHands Yep I have imported. There are same packages contains  httpclient jar file and selenium jar file. Is that a problem?

Comment: @Maduri please check for selenium webdriver version matches the required httpclient-4.2.3 and httpcore-4.2.2..it might be possible that webdriver uses different versions of these http libraries..

Comment: @Maduri - what are you Httpclient and Httpcore versions?

Comment: @VivekSingh Previously I run properly this code. Didn't use any kind of these httpclient or core packages. Only used Selenium jar file. Is that may be a problem?

Comment: @HelpingHands client 4.2.3 and core 4.2.2

Comment: U can try to sysout the resource of BasicLineFormatter.class and check for the proper dependencies it is using.

Comment: @VivekSingh In my selenium server jar file org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter; org.apache.http.message.LineFormatter; contain in the org.apache.http.message package. org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory class contains in the org.apache.http.impl.io package. Is that a problem?  Another thing is both two packages contain in the httpcore-4.2.2 jar file also(Not only the selenium-server jar file). It can't be a problem?

Comment: Its better as suggested by @rupesh update your jars to 3.x and then give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:
[Source Code at Grep](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3-beta1/org/apache/http/impl/io/DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java)

You are missing BasicLineFormatter class from org.apache.http.message package.

Comment: @Tabreji Khan You mean some coding problem? But code is working another package which only contain one jar file. Isn't it because of some conflict with jar files?

Comment: @Tabreji Khan But code is working properly. I'm sure. Do you know what is meaning of dependencies issue and how it solve?

Comment: If you see the source code of DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory at line 52 it is trying to use BasicLineFormatter.INSTANCE. As it is not getting this class things are breaking. Do one thing explore org.apache.http package and see if you can find BasicLineFormatter class in org.apache.http.message and in the same package org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory should be there. Let me know your findings.

Comment: @Tabreji Khan In my selenium server jar file org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter; org.apache.http.message.LineFormatter; contain in the org.apache.http.message package. org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory class contains in the org.apache.http.impl.io package. Is that a problem? But same code, same jar file working properly in another package. Another thing is both two packages contain in the httpcore-4.2.2 jar file also(Not only the selenium-server jar file). It can't be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would  say not this will fix your problem but can you see by including a httpcore 4.2.2 jar file is what your are using currently. Can you try to get the higher one from the [Link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpcorejar.htm) and replace it with current httpcore 4.2.2 and see what difference it makes ?

Comment: But my same code works properly with selenium server jar file this version and that only contained selenium jar file. The problem occurred after I put this code and selenium jar files to this new package which contained huge jar file set.

Comment: From my observation having a different versions also creates a conflict. So that was my first point of concern. We should look at the jar files and their versions included in our package.If possible keep jar files of same version together and check the output.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. After a lot of debugging, I found out that there is a CLASSPATH conflict. A jar file already existing in the project

```
httpclient-osgi-4.2.1.jar
```

was conflicting with selenium jar files. Fortunately for me, the httpclient-osgi-4.2.1.jar file is not required in the project anymore, so I could safely remove it. After that the problem is gone.

The error message is pathetic. It doesn't help in any way to point out the real problem.

Comment: from what package you removed that jar?